# Use Array Within INDEX to get all matches

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Table 1
FRUIT     PRICE
Apple     10
Banana    15 
Mango     20
Pineapple 5
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
SUMIF(Table1[Fruit], INDEX(Table1[Fruit],{1,2}), Table1[Price])
```

In order to add up the prices of fruits number 1 & 2? Totaling in this case 25

Comment: `INDEX(Table1[Fruit],N(IF({1},{1,2})))` as an array formula and wrap the whole in `SUM()`

Comment: Based on your last few questions this will not help you overcome the issue you want.  Using SUMPRODUCT as I did in my answer to your last question is the simplest method to accomplish what you want.  To do what you want with INDEX,  the formula would be very complex and will be slower than the sumproduct I gave you.

Comment: That being said, that all depends on the version, I have been assuming that you do not have the Dynamic Array formula `FILTER()`.  If you do then that all changes and becomes very simple.  Do you have `FILTER()`?

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you very much for your help. The thing is what i actually need isn't exactly what i described in the previous questions i thought i did but when i tried your SUMPRODUCT answer didn't work as it should, ill try to explain it better in my next question, seems you're an Excel master and i hope you could come up with something that works!

Comment: Try the edit I did to that last question.  I had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of sSpill functions, your formula will produce an array or cells, horizontally, for each value in the "{}" clause.

Not in that world? Then not doing CSE will see it obtain only a value for the first cell in the hoped for set of cells, not all of them.

Either way, not what you want.

You can get what you want by "wrapping" your formula with `SUM()`. I know, you're using `SUMIF()` so... why doesn't it sum? Well, it is, but just the first set of returns in the formula, so each cell in the produced Spill array is summed... all by itself... Wrapping it with `SUM()` will sum those individual returns before isolating them to individual cells so you have the single cell with a sum in it.

Another way is to realize that you don't care in the least about the fruits, just the rows they are in and not even that, directly, only as a way to identify the rows to sum up. In other words, why ever bother with anything to do with column A? Just use `INDEX()` within a  `SUM()`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B1:B4,{1,2,4}))
```

will return 30 (10+15+5). No need to overcomplicate.

If one is actaully generating the "{}" portion using something involving the fruit names, you can still use that column in said formula. Otherwise, it is hard to see why one bothers with it...

Comment: If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula, this will not work.